# Двустворчатые или двуХстворчатые окна?

Tags: словоформы

Двуспальный, двусторонний ,двустворчатые.... или двуХстворчатые ?

Answer (score 3):

Все эти слова можно писать и так и так. Лопатин даёт варианты *дву-* и *двухстворчатый* как равнозначные (см. [Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E4%E2%F3%F5%F1%F2%E2%EE%F0%F7%E0%F2%FB%E9&all=x))

Тоже самое касается и остальных приведённых вами слов. Какой вариант написание предпочтёте вы, это уже ваше личное дело. Преимущества и недостатки есть у обоих написаний:

В *двухстворчатом* вместе собирается много согласных, что нехарактерно для русского.

В *двустворчатом* - отсутствует унификация формы *двух-*, встречающихся в других словах. Например, корабль может быть *дву**х**палубным*, но не может быть *дву-*.

Comment: Орфографический словарь тоже дает оба варианта. А вот предложение двусоставное, а не двухсоставное. Или у Лопатина по-другому?

Comment: У Лопатина также, только *двусоставный*.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по сайту, который занимается установкой окон - http://oknaolimpa.ru/product/veka.html - правильно все-таки "двухстворчатым", если разговор идет об окнах.
Вероятно, слово "двустворчатый" уместно в других контекстах.

Comment: На сайте сами могут не знать.

Answer (score 1):

Дву- используется для описания видовых признаков животных или органов.

Двупалый ленивец, двугорбый верблюд, двустворчатый моллюск, двустворчатый клапан сердца.

То есть логика скорее всего указать признак, а не то что верблюд состоит из двух горбов или моллюск из двух створок. Моллюск с одной створкой не жизнеспособен в естественных условиях, не делится. Дву- для неделимых живых объектов. Дву - признак. Спина верблюда состоит из двух горбов - чушь, а два горба растут на спине верблюда - нормально, поэтому двугорбый.

Двухпалубный корабль - это технология, могли одну палубу сдизайнерить, а могли и две, могли и три. Корабль состоит из двух палуб - двухпалубный. А один корабль на две палубы - чушь какая-то.

Поэтому **двухстворчатые окно - окно из двух** створок. Однако, **двуспальная кровать - кровать на два** спальных места, а не из двух спальных мест. Двухспальная - это когда, знаете, берутся две односпальных, сдвигаются рядышком и получается - двухспальная).

Двух - число частей/Дву - признак целого, может штука как с [числительным-местоимением)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474339/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)(?).