# Почему наращение используется после порядковых числительных, но не используется после количественных?

Tags: числительные, наращение

Мне не кажется логичным решение о том, что наращение следует использовать только после порядковых числительных, хотя в официальных текстах я придерживаюсь этого правила. Возможно, здесь есть **какое-то объяснение**, и мне хотелось бы услышать его.

Общий принцип лучше всего рассматривать на конкретных примерах, что я и сделаю.  Сравним два варианта:

**(1)  Порядковое числительное**

***Мальчик учится в 5-м классе.*** Можно написать и так: ***Мальчик учится в 5 классе***, падеж числительного и так понятен (П.п.), но с наращением понятнее.

**(2)  Количественное  числительное**

***Олимпиада проводилась в 5 классах.*** Можно написать и так: ***Олимпиада проводилась в 5-ти  классах**,* падеж числительного понятен (П.п.), но с наращением понятнее.

**Так в чем же разница?**

И еще интересна **история этого правила** (когда и кем было введено, менялось ли впоследствии).

Спасибо.

Вопрос по этой теме: [1000000-н слонов, 100-то вагонов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474321/1000000-%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-100-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2/474322?noredirect=1#comment507151_474322).

Comment: Сто раз объяснял. Цифры без наращения означают количество. Наращение не для того, чтобы был понятен падеж, а для того, чтобы указать, что не количество. Так сложилось в языке. Например: *Возьми 1(-ю) картину.*

Comment: А вы без наращения не видите, что это количество?.. Меня как раз и интересует, почему "так сложилось в языке".  Ну и еще когда "это сложилось", то есть  интересна история вопроса. Хочется следовать понятным указаниям...

Comment: Без наращения количество, а с наращением не количество. В моём примере возможны оба варианта. Вот ещё: *Возьми 3.* Как здесь увидеть, если не было бы наращений? Сложилось так, потому что это очень естественно, логично. Числа были созданы, чтобы считать количество. А чтобы был порядковый номер, нужно дополнение (наращение).

Comment: Наращение тогда, когда числительное приобретает форму прилагательного.

Comment: Согласно теории для числительных, порядковое числительное – это местоименное прилагательное. Кроме того, по тексту видно, какое там числительное. Короче говоря, я не вижу в наращении дополнительной (принципиальной) информации, а вижу только удобную для понимания запись. Докажите,  что там есть такая (необходимая) информация))

Comment: Странно, местоимением здесь и не пахнет. Не всегда видно (примеры выше). И пришлось бы читать, заглядывая наперёд, наращения дают возможность избежать такого неудобного чтения.

Comment: Пахнет, в Грамматике-80 написано.  И вообще, дайте ответ, неудобно обсуждать тему в комментариях. Спасибо.

Comment: И при чём здесь местоимения? Сказал уже всё что мог. А обсуждать можно только в комментариях, иначе никак.

Comment: В общем согласен с oleedd, без наращения числительные обозначают количество.

Comment: Серж, тогда обсудим с вами всё еще раз?)) А вы без наращения не видите, что это количество? И т.д. Тут еще от падежа многое зависит. В Т.п. и П.п. очень хочется добавить наращение, но нельзя! Ошибка это! И грамотные люди обязательно укажут на ошибку менее грамотным пользователям. А если те скажут: почему это? Ваш ответ не покажется им убедительным. И про историю правила можете что-нибудь сказать?

Comment: @Sharon, как понять: "А вы без наращения не видите, что это количество?"

Comment: Это начало нашей дискуссии с oleedd, в ходе которой  мы не пришли к единому мнению. Он говорил:  без наращения количество, а с наращением не количество (порядок при счете). А мы разве так (без наращения)  не видим, где количество,  а где порядок. Я же теперь считаю, что с помощью  наращения мы подчеркиваем связь согласования, характерную для порядковых числительных как грамматических  прилагательных.

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос про дву- и двух- связан как раз с этой темой.

Comment: @Sharon Тоже никак не мог понять этот ваш вопрос. Он нелогичный. Вы пишете "без наращения", а когда количество, наращение не делается. Надо было о порядке говорить. Ну вот вы к тому же и пришли, только по-другому сформулировали. Подчёркиваем для того, чтобы было понятно, что прилагательное, то есть не чисто число.

Comment: Вам нужна подсказка (наращение), чтобы отличить количественное числительное от порядкового, вы их так не различаете. А мне нужно наращение, чтобы уточнить окончание, причем это не помешает в обоих случаях.  Разницу чувствуете? Я бы написала так: из 30-ти пассажиров, мне так удобнее. Что в этом плохого?  А правило запрещает.

Comment: @Буратино
 Я видела ваш ответ и в основном с ним согласна. В той теме, как мне думается, надо противопоставить чисто количественное и качественное значение  форм ДВУ и ДВУХ. Здесь как бы усечение формы ДВУХ до ДВУ, это не наращение.  В теме наращений тоже противопоставлены две формы, но как именно? Только чтобы отличить количественные числительные от порядковых? Разве мы их так не различаем? Или зачем?

Comment: Ну и различите в моём примере про картину. Таких ситуаций масса. Мне ничего не нужно, говорю, как сложилось в языке. У вас очередное новаторство, идите в РАН (она же рядом) и предлагайте реформы.

Comment: Изначально у меня было 21, но решил упростить.

Comment: @Sharon 21 надо писать буквами? Слишком длинно. У вас почему-то 5 записано цифрой. Мне такое неправильное новаторство не нужно. Свежий ветер нужен в искусстве, а не в лингвистике. Ладно, скажу вам чётко, как оно есть, раз вы поёте ту же песню. Число само по себе прилагательным не является. Число, записанное цифрами, это не какой, это сколько. У самой по себе цифры нет функции передачи порядкового номера. Цифры не для этого создавали.

Comment: Это для меня лишком сложно... Вм нужен другой собеседник. И почитайте Грамматику-80.

Comment: @Sharon Прокачивайте мозги. Человек с прокачанными мозгами может за пару лет разобраться в этом всём гораздо лучше, чем человек без прокачанных мозгов, который занимается этим десятилетия.

Comment: А вам уже, кажется, прокачали мозги, какой-то вы весь обновлённый, даже стиль речи изменился...

Comment: Мозги только самому надо прокачивать, прокачивание кем-то малоэффективно. Нет, тот же стиль, просто использую сленговые слова.

Comment: Со стороны на себя посмотрите...

Comment: Мне кажется, или "прокачай мозги" это слоган из рекламы шоколадных батончиков?) А не, там было заряди мозги. Прокачай - это что-то новое.

Comment: @Буратино Не знаю, может быть. Но это точно не первоисточник. Может, от "прокачать персонажа".

Comment: Может, там"заряжай мозги"? А Олид интересно каким способом себе мозги прокачивает https://dzen.ru/a/YE29VBJqPUVaxmR1

Comment: @Sharon Советую вам добро. Вы так будете десятилетиями с элементарными вещами разбираться. Надо решать головоломки, математические задачи, задачи по программированию и т.п. Путей много.

Comment: прокачка мозгов напоминает методы Илоны Давыдовой) ничего не делал, спал, а проснулся зная ин яз

Comment: @Sharon По этой ссылке вода водой. Ни одного нормального пункта нет.

Comment: Нет, вы точно другой..  Только в фантастике такие сюжеты встретишь.

Comment: У мужчин бывают прокачанные мозги, а у женщин бывает интуиция. Олед, колись где-что прокачал), а то тебя не узнали. Ну в этом точно что-то есть, ты как тот страус из мультика, который ворона встретил и тот его прокачивал на полёт)

Comment: Думаю, что классно быть разным. Иначе мы биороботы, которые ведут себя одинаково (по заложенным алгоритмам).

Comment: Поняли, у меня интуиция!

Comment: @Sharon Интуиция не для лингвистики, не для науки.

Comment: Я же все задачи решаю интуитивно, пока вы там со своими правилами разбираетесь))

Comment: Так нельзя, вы же не экстрасенс. Да и экстрасенсы постоянно промахиваются. Нет такого метода в науке, это житейский метод.

Comment: Тут или ворон или скорее другая птица, какой-то ты воздушный, одухотворенный: "мы не биороботы, которые ведут себя одинаков..." Хотя у меня интуиция работает наоборот и я вряд ли угадаю)

Comment: Методы разные, а главное - это результат.

Comment: Такой одухотворенный робот...

Comment: Результат зависит от надёжности методов. А интуиция — самый ненадёжный метод.

Comment: Ничего, человека тоже из глины слепили, тут главное одухотворенность)

Comment: Если тебя подводит интуиция, это просто значит, что ты не женщина), так что ты прав, но интуиция твоя ошиблась)

Comment: Вы недовольны моими решениями задач (интуитивными)? Авторы вопросов вроде бы не жалуются.

Comment: @Sharon Нет, недоволен вашим непониманием очевидных вещей.

Comment: А как им жаловаться? Они же вас не проверяют.

Comment: А вас, с вашими вечными поисками истины и правды,  разве проверяют?

Comment: Мы здесь все друг друга проверяем. У меня нет поисков истины. Просто я здесь как бы вестник истины. Всё началось с фразы "это для меня лишком сложно". Чтобы не было сложно, надо прокачивать мозги...

Comment: А кончилось вашей одухотворенностью?

Comment: Нет у меня одухотворённости. Всё как обычно.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Вы заразились. Ничего хорошего в этом нет. Частица "таки" смысл имеет, её нельзя пихать куда угодно.

Comment: А это уже наш  Вестник истины. Все молчат и слушают...  А вы не могли бы придумать правильную фразу с ТАКИ?

Comment: @Sharon Таки — это всё-таки. Вот и придумайте, чтобы было в тему. А там: *Веселится всё-таки весь народ всё-таки.*

Comment: Вот вам суперкраткий и суперпонятный ответ: "второй" — это не цифра, не число, поэтому нельзя тупо записывать цифрой.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю свою версию ответа. Для всего есть причина, так что попробуем **обосновать** правило.

**(1) Количественные  числительные**

Короткие числа рекомендуется записывать не цифрами, а буквами. Так текст **удобнее читать**. ***Семь** бед – один ответ. Обещанного **три** года ждут. Заблудиться в **трёх** соснах.*

Если число большое, то используют **цифровую запись**, причем **без наращений**: *Из 30 карточек с буквами русского алфавита наудачу выбирают 4 карточки.*
Как видно, здесь первое число записано цифрами, поэтому цифровая запись используется и для второго.

**Наращение** (обозначение формы числительного) не используется. **Согласование или управление** как вид связи в количественном обороте определяется по падежной форме существительного.

**(2) Порядковые  числительные**

Порядковые  числительные являются **грамматическими прилагательными**, что определяется по форме. К классу грамматических числительных их не относят (это верно только в условной школьной классификации).

Поэтому форму порядкового числительного **желательно обозначить на письме,** если мы используем цифровую запись: *передвижение **30-й армии**.*

Здесь тоже окончание порядкового числительного можно определить в сочетании с существительным, то есть **обойтись без наращения**. Но в этом случае важно **подчеркнуть связь «согласование»** для грамматического **прилагательного**, которая используется в словосочетании.

**P.S.** В ответе учтены мнения,  высказанные в ходе дискуссии.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** (о порядковых числительных)

**Грамматика-80** http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html (учебник по морфологии и другим разделам)

Термин "числительное" традиционно употребляется также для наименования **всех слов с количественно-числовым и счетно-порядковым** значениями. Такие слова отвечают на вопросы "сколько?" и "который?": два, три, пятеро, тысяча, миллион, нуль (и ноль); первый, второй, десятый, сотый.

Слова эти принадлежат к **разным частям речи**: к числительным, существительным, прилагательным; их объединяет то что все они являются **счетными словами**…

**Счетно-порядковые** прилагательные типа второй, третий, десятый (называемые иногда также **порядковыми числительными**), а также счетно-местоименное слово один не имеют своих собственных, отличающих их **от прилагательных** морфологических признаков. С другой стороны, такие слова, как миллион, миллиард, нуль, не имеют морфологических признаков, отличающих их от существительных.

Comment: *Согласование или управление в количественном обороте определяется по существительному*. Добавил бы: *по существительному и предлогу*.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я лучше напишу «…определяется по падежной форме существительного», а предлог как раз и задает падеж